# variable log_bin value off - what does it mean?

Tags: mysql, sql, configuration, config

I've edited my.cnf file to enable binary logging. Configuration I used is as follows:

```
[ mysqld ]

log-bin= /var/lib/mysql/localhost-mysql-bin.log

binlog-format = mixed
```

than I logged in as root to my server (on my computer, localhost that is) and used following command to check whether my bin_log is actually on:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'log_bin';
```

and I got this:

```
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| log_bin       | OFF   |
+---------------+-------+
```

From what I gather is that I didn't suceed. Or does it mean that I haven't got any logs yet?

Comment: Firstly, I suggest you to remove spaces after and/or before the = character in the configuration line and then "reload" or "force-reload" your new configuration.

Comment: I did do that but it doesn't change anything. Still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so there was nothing wrong with my configuration. Simple restart did the job and mysql picked up on changes. Problem solved.